# WooCommerce add custom adress data to orders

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a friend/customer using WordPress and WooCommerce for his web order system. We need to store custom data in order info.

The info is the corrected address info which we can get from a third party provider's REST API. The info contains corrected street, city info, latitude and longitude values. Since Google Maps' address search is shitty in our country and Users sometimes make typo errors.

We want to store this additional info and send to Zapier. Zapier sends the latititude and longitude values to delivery guy's screen.

I'm a newbie to WordPress. I know PHP and use it to create web apps in my own way so I'm not familiar with WordPress' hooking scheme. I know I need to hook something in `functions.php` but I don't know where to start.

Thank you for answers.

Answer (score 1):

first of all, themes are made to display datas and not to work with datas.
then, to make special works on checkout, you can create a plugin :
https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/the-basics/#getting-started

afterward, the action that will help you is `woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta`, it appends on the creation of the order :
http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Checkout.html#329

Comment: Thank you. I was avoiding writing a plugin but It seems I have to write one. :)